# Glide : You cannot start a load on a fragment before it is attached

Tags: android, android-glide

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.zihadrizkyef.project_katalog_grosirmukenalukis_user, PID: 15458
                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a fragment before it is attached
                                                   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:110)
                                                   at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:678)
                                                   at com.zihadrizkyef.project_katalog_grosirmukenalukis_user.FragmentViewProduct$1.onResponse(FragmentViewProduct.java:190)
                                                   at com.zihadrizkyef.project_katalog_grosirmukenalukis_user.FragmentViewProduct$1.onResponse(FragmentViewProduct.java:139)
                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:921)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:716)
```

I got this error when i open fragmentA, then immediatelly go to fragmentB, then immediattelly back to fragmentA. I think i got this error if my phone or its internet is laggy, i don't know. This is my code :

**FragmentViewProduct.java**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    downloadSignature = new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    loadProductData();
}

private void loadProductData() {
    StringRequest srLoadData = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MainActivity.SERVER_URL + "/product/readproduct.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (responseJSON.getBoolean("success")) {
                            ...
                            Glide.with(FragmentViewProduct.this)
                                    .load(MainActivity.SERVER_URL+"/product/asset/"+listImageUrl.getString(i))
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                                    .error(R.drawable.noimage)
                                    .signature(downloadSignature)
                                    .into(ivImageChild);
                            lyImageList.addView(ivImageChild);
                            }
                        } else {
                            MainActivity.showToast(responseJSON.getString("message"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    MainActivity.showToast(error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", String.valueOf(idToRead));
            return params;
        }
    };
    volleyRequestQueue.add(srLoadData);
}
```

Comment: You should not load data on `onResume()` in `Fragment`, load data `onActivityCreated()` method of Fragment. As this method is called when fragment is totally attached and its views are initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. But if i see Fragment's lifecycle it shows that onResume() is more under than onActivityCreated(), so onResume() should work like onActivityCreated() is working.. Can you explain this to me? i am newbie in android

Comment: And is onActivityCreated() called if i pause the app then resume it?

Comment: `onActivityCreated()` is called only when the first time the fragment and its views have finally been laid out. And also called again when fragment and activity is recreated.